# How to setup silent log in to web application?

Tags: authentication

I am creating a small business web application. 
All my clients access their application from their office. 
To make their life easy, I have put a code that will look where the request is coming from. if the request is coming from IP-address AAA then it is my customer A. I would automatically log in (on the server side) and present the customer logged in page, removing the need to supply the user and password.

would you know any other way to allow my customers to log in to the web application securely without supplying the user and password?

Answer (score 0):

As a recommendation, you should use [Single Sign-on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). Your users only need to log once in order to use the service and you can avoid to type an user/password combination every time.